# Renaming sheet in all Excel files in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am new to Python. I have a folder with multiple files with the same sheet name. I just need to rename the current sheet name to a different name.

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl 
ss=openpyxl.load_workbook('name1.xlsx')
ss=openpyxl.load_workbook('name2.xlsx')
#more files
      
for sheet in ss:
    sheet_name = sheet.title
    sheet.title = "All Data"
    ss.save('name1.xlsx')
    ss.save('name2.xlsx')
    #more files to save
```

For example, I want to change 'Sheet1' to 'All Data.' Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, the basic concept it there, but what you have is messed up, because you're overwriting the "ss" variable each time.  If you want to do this to all the Excel files in the folder, try the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use os library if the purpose is only to rename the file.

```
import os
os.rename(r'C:\Users\Abc\File.txt, r'C:\Users\Abc\NewFileName.txt)
```

However if you do have the multiple files inside a directory you may refer to this geeksforgeeks solution.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python/

Further Note that File will not renamed if it is opened at the moment.

Comment: He doesn't want to rename the files, he wants to rename the sheets within the files.

Comment: Ah I got it. I thought its related to renaming file

Answer (score 0):

The openpyxl documentation is not very good.  I can't find how to rename a sheet.  The `active` property of the workbook will give you the active sheet, maybe that's enough.  What that means is I don't know if this code actually works, because I can't find the info in openpyxl, but the philosophy is right.  You might look at `xlsxwriter`.

```
import glob
import openpyxl

for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):  
    ss = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    ss.active.name = ss.active.title
    ss.active.title = "All Data"
    ss.save(file)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, actually, this works for me. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl
ss=openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ss_sheet = ss['Old Sheet Name']
ss_sheet.title = 'New Sheet Name'
ss.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Just checked. Its working fine.